# Conditional probability and Poisson processes

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Good afternoon :). I have a problem I am stuck on in conditional probability, because I am not sure about some steps. I checked for similar posts, but I am actually looking to understand some specific steps of my reasoning, so I hope you won't hold me accountable if a similar problem was once posted.

Ok, so say I have two random variables $X$ And $Y$ following Poisson processes of parameters respectively $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

It is quite straightforward to see that the probability that $X$ happens first, for instance, is $\dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2}$.

But now, say we know that at $t = 1$, the event $X$ has happened once.

***Problem: What is the expected time at which the first even (of X and Y) happened?***

Ok so I decided to split it into two cases. Call $1_X$ the event that $X$ happens first (given that $X$ only happens once in the interval $(0,1)$, and call $1_Y$ the event that $Y$ happens first.

---

- First case. Assume $1_X$, so $X$ happens first, say at time $t \in (0,1)$. The time to the event follows and exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_1$,so we could argue that the expectation of $(X|1_X)$ is simply the expectation of this exponential distribution over $(0,1)$, which is $1 - e^{-\lambda_1}$.

But then I started wondering... is that correct? Have we **accounted** for the fact that no other $X-$event happens in the interval $(t, 1)$? Because it might be the case that $X$ happens another time between $t$ and $1$, which then contradicts our hypothesis that $X$ happened once at $t = 1$.

This is my first question, I will label it *Q1* to make my post (and maybe the answers) clearer.

---

- Second case: Y happens first. We have no condition on the number of times Y has to happen. All we require is that $X$ happens once between $t = 0$ and $t = 1$ (call $t_X$ the time at which $X$ happens).

I made even less progress on that case because I don't know how to treat the fact that we need $Y$ to happen between $t = 0$ and $t = t_X$. If we did not have this condition, then the expected time would simply be $1 - e^{-\lambda_2}$, because we would integrate an exponential random variable over $(0,1)$.

But here, do we integrate the exponential random variable over $(0,t_X)$, and then do another integration over the range of $t_X$?... (This is my second question, I will label it *Q2*).

---

I'm sorry if this post is not clear enough. I am quite confused because I never really know, in conditional probability, if something has been accounted for already or not. So I don't really know how to deal with that problem.

Thank you for your answer. Let me know if something needs clarification.

Comment: To clarify, I think you are asking about $E[\min[X,Y] | X<1]$, where $X,Y$ are independent exponential with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.  Is that it?  [Your talk of some "other $X$ event" is confusing to me. Note that $X$ is a random variable, not an event. I believe there are only 2 random variables $X,Y$ in the problem, no more.]

Comment: Yes, my bad, I said an "X-event" to mean an event corresponding to the X poisson process, sorry if that was not clear. But that is the probability I am trying to figure out indeed :)

Comment: You can compute $P[\min[X,Y]>z | X<1]$ using definition of conditional probability.  Remember that the min is bigger than $z$ if and only if both are.

Comment: That is a really good point. So this just ends up being $P(min[X,Y] \leq 1 | X < 1) = 1 - P(z < X < 1)P(Y > z)$ if I'm not mistaken? And then just have to integrate it from $z = 0$ to $z = 1$? :)

Comment: You have not used the definition of conditional probability.  It seems you are trying to jump to step 2  (doing a "one minus" thing) before you give a complete answer to step 1 of just computing $P[\min[X,Y]>z|X<1]$. Of course, knowing what step 2 will be is useful for understanding why we care about step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer has been posted in the comments, I need to consider the expectation of the minimum of $X$ and $Y$, which eventually comes down to being the expectation of the minimum of a uniform and an exponential random variables.